# How do I do multiple browser operations with c#?

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am using c # selenium. However, I tried several browsers, but the computer is using too many CPUs. How does the back panel work in multiple browsers without CPU exhaustion?

Could you give a code sample?

```
public static IWebDriver[] twitter;

twitter = new IWebDriver[5];

            for (int i=0; i<5;i++)
            {
                twitter[i] = new ChromeDriver();
            }

            foreach (var drivers in twitter)
            {
                drivers.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.google.com.tr");
            }
```

these operations are very tedious. very tiring. and very complicated. I also do not know whether the series can be done? Is there an example that will save the CPU?

Comment: Could you give a code example?

Comment: Show us what you have tried...

Comment: I created a short code. I started the file 5 times. Then 5 different browsers opened and each exe managed a browser, but the CPU was too high.

Comment: You have code for this right? If you do, see if you can add it to your question, people are more willing to help after you show what you have done

Comment: I need a method to manage all browsers from just one file. this could be with the selenium library or something else. my goal is to manage all browsers with an exe without having to eat the CPU.

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve].

Comment: I added a short example :)

Comment: Put Selenium to one side. Load up five tabs in Chrome and load those URLs. How much CPU is being used?

Comment: He's using 10%. but when he manages with the selenium library it goes up two floors or even three floors. and managing multiple browsers is really difficult because you have to write code for each driver. writing the same codes over and over is tedious and pointless. I'm browsing some programs and they open up 50 tabs on the backplane so I do not know how they do it.

Answer (score 0):

You could try out with multiple tabs as shown here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pZdMsLKAjs4

Since this is not an answer, I wanted to add it as a comment, but I can't because of low rep. sorry for that.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but as you said you did not answer the question. window-window operations are progressing in order. It does not focus on a single process at the same time. I guess this is a minus feature of the selenium library. For example, when I send a command to multiple tabs with for, it does not send the command to the top tier without executing a tab command :) at the same time it consumes excessive ram and CPU.

Comment: If you tell more about your workflow that might help.